# Heavy calculation required and shared between two behaviours in coupled strategy pattern. Where should it be done and held

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am using strategy pattern to have a calculation model which can have different behaviours.

*[snippet1]*

```
class BehaviourInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourInterface() {}
    virtual double func() = 0;
};

class Model
{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BehaviourInterface>> behaviours_;
};

class BehaviourA : public BehaviourInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourA(double a) : BehaviourInterface(), a_(a), c_(0) {}
    double func() { return a_; }
private:
    double a_;
};

class BehaviourB : public BehaviourInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourB(double b) : BehaviourInterface(), b_(b) {}
    double func() { return b_; }
private:
    double b_;
};
```

And I can then create a model with two behaviours. In this example, the model simply sums the values from each behaviour.

*[snippet2]*

```
class SomeModel : public Model
{
public:
    SomeModel()
    {
        // Construct model with a behaviourA and behaviourB.
        behaviours_.push_back(std::shared_ptr<BehaviourInterface>(new BehaviourA(1))); 
        behaviours_.push_back(std::shared_ptr<BehaviourInterface>(new BehaviourB(2)));
    }

    double GetResult()
    {   
        // Sum the values from each behaviour.
        double result = 0;
        for (auto bItr = behaviours_.begin(); bItr != behaviours_.end(); ++bItr)
            result += (*bItr)->func();
        return result;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SomeModel sm;
    double result = sm.GetResult();     // result = behaviourA + behaviourB = 1 + 2 = 3;
}
```

Works nicely, allows me to implement different behaviours, each behaviour is sandboxed from all other behaviours (decoupled strategy).

I extended this slightly to allow the behaviours have access to the model they belong (by introducing another behaviour interface which holds the model), which allows a behaviour to be able to hook into another behaviour via the model that both behaviours belong. In this regard it's not pure strategy patten (since behaviours can know about other behaviours), however it can still be generic enough so that behaviours do not need to know implementation details of other behaviours. e.g.

I introduce `BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface`

*[snippet3]*

```
class BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface : public BehaviourInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface(Model& model) : model_(model) {}
protected:
    Model& model_;
}
```

And `BehaviourA` and `BehaviourB` derive from the newer interface...

*[snippet4]*

```
class BehaviourA : public BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourA(Model& model, double a) : BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface(model), a_(a), c_(0) {}
    double func() { return a_; }
private:
    double a_;
};

class BehaviourB : public BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourB(Model& model, double b) : BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface(model), b_(b) {}
    double func() { return b_; }
private:
    double b_;
};
```

This means I can change the way I get the result from the model by having one of the behaviours perform the logic that `Model::GetResult()` used to do.

e.g. I change `BehaviourA::func()` to now add its value with `BehaviourB`'s value.

*[snippet5]*

```
class BehaviourA : public BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourA(Model& model, double a) : BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface(model), a_(a), c_(0) {}
    double func() 
    {
        // Get the value of behaviourB, and add to this behaviours value..
        return a_ + model_.behaviours_[1].func();
    }
private:
    double a_;
};
```

Then `SomeModel::GetResult()` becomes...

*[snippet6]*

```
class SomeModel : public Model
{
public:
    SomeModel()
    {
        // Construct model with a behaviourA and behaviourB.
        behaviours_.push_back(std::shared_ptr<BehaviourInterface>(new BehaviourA(1))); 
        behaviours_.push_back(std::shared_ptr<BehaviourInterface>(new BehaviourB(2)));
    }

    double GetResult()
    {   
        // Just get the result from behaviourA, as this will add BehaviourB as part of BehaviourA's implementation.
        double result = behaviours_[0].func();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SomeModel sm;
    double result = sm.GetResult();     // result = behaviourA = 1 + behaviourB = 1 + 2 = 3
}
```

So `BehaviourA` can now only be part of a `Model` which has a `BehaviourB`. Not pure strategy pattern (as there is dependency of one behaviour to another behaviour), but this restriction is still ok as these behaviours can be extended again giving elements of the flexability of strategy pattern, albeit in limited capcity compared to the original example (TIL this is called coupled strategy ;)).

*[snippet7]*

```
class BehaviourAInterface : public BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourAInterface(Model& model) : BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface(model) {}
    virtual double funcA() {}
    double func() { return funcA(); }
}

class BehaviourBInterface : public BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourBInterface(Model& model) : BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface(model) {}
    virtual double funcA() {}
    double func() { return funcB(); }
}
```

And then the behaviour implementations become...

*[snippet8]*

```
class BehaviourA : public BehaviourAInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourA(Model& model, double a) : BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface(model), a_(a), c_(0) {}
    double funcA() { return a_; }
private:
    double a_;
};

class BehaviourB : public BehaviourBInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourB(Model& model, double b) : BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface(model), b_(b) {}
    double funcB() { return b_; }
private:
    double b_;
};
```

And this means I can still use the situation that `BehaviourA` knows about `BehaviourB` (*snippet5* & *snippet6*), yet still the implementation details of B are unknown by A.

i.e.

```
class BehaviourA : public BehaviourAInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourA(Model& model, double a) : BehaviourAInterface(model), a_(a), c_(0) {}
    double funcA() { return a_ + model_.behaviours_[1].func(); }
private:
    double a_;
};
```

Still holds, same as before for *snippet5* and *snippet6*.

## The problem

The problem I have is that, with certain `BehaviourA`'s and `BehaviourB`'s, they use a common calculated value and this value is heavy to calculate so I only want to do it once but want it used by both behaviours (potentially). I do not want this calculated value to part of the behaviourA or B interface as there can be other behaviourA's or B's that do not use it, and it also implies that both behaviours may have to implement it since they can't rely on the other having it.

To address this there a number of different solutions that can be used but I'm not too sure which one is correct/best to use.

## Solution 1

The model has this implementation to calculate it, and holds an optional so it is only calculated once.

```
class Model
{
public:
    double CalculateC() 
    { 
        if (c_)
            return *c_;
        c_ = SomeHeavyCalculation();        // c_ not set yet, so calculate it (heavy heavy calc).
        return c_;
    }
private:
    std::optional<double> c_;
}
```

Pros:
Neither `BehaviourA` or `BehaviourB` have to hold it.

Neither `BehaviourA` or `BehaviourB` needs to know about each other (nod towards decoupled strategy pattern)

Any behaviour can use it.

Cons:
Not every behaviour (or any behaviour in some implementations) may even require it.

Model is now somewhat specialised and looses some generalisation.

Model may turn into some uber state object holding all possible values which may or may not be used by different behaviours. Messy large interface potentially.

## Solution 2

A 'Model global state' object which can hold arbitary values which some behaviours may populate, and others use.

```
class ModelState
{
public:
    double GetC() 
    { 
        if (c_)
            return *c_;
        c_ = SomeHeavyCalculation();        // c_ not set yet, so calculate it (heavy heavy calc).
        return c_;
    }
private:
    std::optional<double> c_;
}
```

Which is held by the `Model`, and behaviours can use it (or populate it if not there)

```
class Model
{
public:
    ModelState& GetModelState() { return modelState_; }
private:
    ModelState modelState_;
}
```

Pros:
Decouples `Model` from state meaning `Model` remains generalised, and its behaviours have dependencies on the `ModelState` object that it used. (when `Model` is instantiated, it can deduce which state object it reuires, based on which behaviours are used).

Any behaviour can trigger the heavy calc, so behaviour invocation ordering is agnostic.

Cons:
Requires some logic to deduce which state objects to use. More complexity required with instantiating.

Some state objects may end being uber objects containing loads of things which may or may not be used by different behaviours. Introduce some more behaviour's which use a model 'global' value, and potentially I have to introduce other state objects to hold this model 'global' value.

## Solution 3

Introduce another behaviour to do this.

```
class BehaviourC : public BehaviourInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourC() : BehaviourInterface() {}
    double func() 
    { 
        if (c_)
            return *c_;
        c_ = SomeHeavyCalculation();        // c_ not set yet, so calculate it (heavy heavy calc).
        return c_;
    }
private:
    std::optional<double> c_;
};
```

Pros:
Keeps `Model` generalised, doesn't reduce strategy pattern flexability more than it already is when using the design that behaviours can know 'something' about other behaviours (again not a totally pure strategy pattern, but still flexible).

Cons:
How granular do we want to go with behaviours performing operations that other behaviours require (although thinking about it, this would be similar to rule of three refactor... if two or more behaviours require something that is heavy to calc, that 'heavy to calc' thing becomes another behaviour).

Dependancy of behaviours can turn into  minefield... suddenly to use `BehaviourA`, we need `BehaviourC`, `BehaviourB` `BehaviourD` etc... while I have already introduced this potential dependency's between behaviours (the coupling), it is currently fairly minimal and would like to keep it as minimal as possible.

Having another `Behaviour` means in future the list could get large and thus loosing even more purity of the behaviour patter and requiring a big list of depdencies given some behaviour. Very coupled!

## Solution 4

Each behaviour calculates it's own value.

```
class BehaviourA : public BehaviourAInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourA(Model& model, double a) : BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface(model), a_(a) {}
    double funcA() { return SomeHeavyCalculation() + a_; }
private:
    double a_;
};

class BehaviourB : public BehaviourBInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourB(Model& model, double b) : BehaviourWithModelKnowledgeInterface(model), b_(b) {}
    double funcB() { return SomeHeavyCalculation() + b_; }
private:
    double b_;
};
```

Pros:
Each behaviour can be somewhat sandboxed and does not have requirement on another behaviour, even if another behaviour uses the same calculated value. Increased decoupling.

Cons:
The `SomeHeavyCalculation()` calculation is performed twice by each behaviour. This is exactly what I'm trying to mitigate!

This calc itself may want to be implemented differently (which actually points to Solution 3 being the best solution).

## I dunno what to do ????

Solution 1 I don't like as I would prefer a more generalised model interface and don't want it to become some uber concrete class.
Solution 2 I think is better than 1, however suffers the same problems that may occur in Solution 1 with the state becoming an uber interface. It also means more headache in terms of maintenece as there needs to be some logic or design which relates to the behaviours to use the correct state objects given the behaviours in a model. Coupling is now not just between behaviours, but also there corresponding state objects.

Solution 3 is my gut feeling about what should be done, but what worries me is that some point in the future... all of the sudden, to use `BehaviourA` I need a `BehaviourC`, to use C I need a D etc... heavy coupling may occur, making it hard to construct certain models without knowing to include other strategies.

I really don't know which one to use or if I am using this pattern correctly to it's full potential.... or if I should be using another pattern (which I am unaware of). Apologies for the length of the question and I really hope I am not missing something obvious here.

Comment: What you can do is figure out a way to reduce your question to about 1/20th of its current size. I will be very surprised if someone here, for some reason, invests an hour of their time trying to read through it all, understand the code, figure out what's being asked here, and just so happens to also know the answer.

Comment: Your base classes Model & BehaviourInterface lack the necessary virtual destructor. This doesn't have something to do with your question put i think it should be pointed out.

Comment: thats lots of code and text to read. I second Sam in that you should condese the question a bit. Also note that the actual power of a design pattern comes into play when you actually have to change something, not so much at the time you lay out the initial implementation

Comment: High level of bloat is unusual need in programming. Why you need it? Better write some python script to generate such bloat patterns if you are dissatisfied with levels of bloat.

Comment: None of your approaches make any sense to me. It is already a bad design to make Behaviors dependent on the Model. Even worse to ask model to hold some temporary stuff needed by behaviors. If you need to share the resource that needs to be calculated once, just go for Singleton and make it visible only to Behaviors.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes I appreicate the length is a bit long and potentially offputting :(. I thought it might be wise to outline the context in which this issue has arised in the real world problem.

Comment: @Eric Yes noted, this is just a quick example I had to type up. Not too worried about leaks with this example ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes I appreciate that. The problem is already real world in trying to modularise a potentially massive calculation model which can have potentially lots of different behaviours. The situation arises that some of those behaviours use common values which are heavy to calc. So I was wondering how to incoporate these values within the current strategy behaviour. I think Solution 3 is the right approach but as I said in the qu, has it's own pitfalls.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Sorry I'm not follwing? whats the bloat?

Comment: Upvoting for detailed question, and listing what you have tried.

Comment: @pptaszni Thanks, pretty much the only comment which came somewhere near to answering the question. Yes singleton was a thought we had, but the problem arises that this may in itselfs be strategy with differing implementations depending on the data and context currently available for performing the calc. I'm thinking it should be a strategy itself, but then leads to complexities in itself and means the `model` requires perhaps many more building blocks than might be nice to mange in order to just achieve what is needed.

Comment: @pptaszni Yes I agree behaviours should not depedant on the model, but in this example the behaviours know about the model so that ehy can know what other behaviour (types) are current in this model. These models can be complex can have a host of different strategies which perhaps vary slightly (hence the pattern). And yes definately the model shouldn't hold stuff for the behaviours hence the qu asking about where this should potentially be done?

Comment: @lfgtm it seems you are just inventing as bloat ways as only possible for unknown reason ... perhaps to replace lambdas that return double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is passing whatever pre-computed values to the behaviors *in their constructor*, so that you have the following calling code:

```
const double x = SomeHeavyCalculation();
const double y = SomethingElseWhichIsHeavy();

Behavior1 b1(..., x);
Behavior2 b2(..., y);
Behavior3 b3(..., x, y);
```

That way the behaviors still have the same interface and do not depend on each other:

```
b1.func();
b2.func();
b3.func();
```

Now, you can generalize this by decomposing your behaviors into sub-steps and share those sub-steps between all behaviors. You could model the steps as objects/behaviors, too, rather than raw values, and cache the results etc.

Further, you can generalize more and allow a graph of computations to take place, with any dependencies (even between them), and automatically compute the best approach to solve the graph, cache intermediate results and even paralellize the tasks. Of course, that is a major effort, but it is what general task-based frameworks do.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer basing on the comments, the question is a bit over-complicated though. Your behaviors `BehaviorA` and `BehaviorB` both need the access to some common resource, and this resource can also be slightly dependent on the model, right? Let's do this:

```
class BehaviourInterface
{
public:
  virtual ~BehaviourInterface() = default;
  virtual double func() = 0;
};

class ICommonResourcesGenerator
{
public:
  virtual ~ICommonResourcesGenerator() = default;
  virtual double gimmeMyresource() = 0;
};

class Gen1: public ICommonResourcesGenerator
{
public:
  ~Gen1() override = default;
  double gimmeMyresource() override {
    if (!needToCalculate()) return res_;
    calculate();
    return res_;
  }

private:
  bool needToCalculate() { return res_ < 0; }  // or whatever check you need to do
  void calculate() { /* calc */ }
  static double res_;
}

double Gen1::res_ = -1;

class BehaviourA : public BehaviourInterface
{
public:
  BehaviourA(double a, std::shared_ptr<ICommonResourcesGenerator> gen):
  a_(a), gen_(gen) {}
  double func() { return a_ + gen_->gimmeMyresource(); }
private:
  double a_;
  std::shared_ptr<ICommonResourcesGenerator> gen_;
};

class BehaviourB : public BehaviourInterface
{
public:
    BehaviourB(double b, std::shared_ptr<ICommonResourcesGenerator> gen):
    b_(b), gen_(gen) {}
    double func() { return b_ + gen_->gimmeMyresource(); }
private:
    double b_;
    std::shared_ptr<ICommonResourcesGenerator> gen_;
};
```

Then your model can initialize the desired behaviors with the appropriate shared resources generators:

```
class SomeModel
{
public:
  SomeModel() {
    behaviours_.push_back(std::shared_ptr<BehaviourInterface>(
      new BehaviourA(1, std::make_shared<Gen1>()))); 
    behaviours_.push_back(std::shared_ptr<BehaviourInterface>(
      new BehaviourB(2, std::make_shared<Gen1>())));
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BehaviourInterface> > behaviours_;
};
```

Alternatively, you might have `double res_` as non-static field of the particular generator, and keep `std::shared_ptr<Gen>` in your `Model` as a private field created once when model is created. "It all depends ... ".

Anyway, this approach guarantees that both behaviors A and B will be able to access the same resource without calculating it more than once, and that the kind of resource is unknown to A and B, but is decided by Model.